# PHP files does not execute in windows machine

Tags: php, file-permissions, chmod

i created the application in PHP on my mac osx. and after the development i zipped and transferred to the windows 7 machine. and when i tried opening it i get this error.

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/app/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

the above error suggest, the error is caused because of the file permission issue, is there any possible way i can fix this error in windows itself.?

thank you..

Comment: Right click on the folder `C:/wamp`, select Properties -> Permissions (or something) and choose Read and Write for your user and apply recursively. I'm not on Windows so I can't tell you the exact procedure, but that is what I would try.

Comment: tried it, but does not seems to work :(

Comment: i installed WAMP server on windows machine, and i am able to successfully run phpMyAdmin. the issue is only with the directory i uploaded

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this and found that it was because the index.php file was set with encryption.

For anyone that wants to rule it out - right click the php file, select 'properties' then click the 'advanced' button and uncheck the 'Encrypt contents to secure data' check box and click 'O.K'. This worked for me, so just putting it out there.

Comment: Thanks, it helped for WAMP on Windows to [disable encrypting files](http://www.technipages.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/Windows-file-encryption-setting.png) It resolved the errors such as **failed to open stream: No such file or directory** and sometimes there was some **SCREAM** error

Answer (score 4):

In your cmd try to run your project with the following command

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

Comment: Thanks for the `-t` tip. In my case it was `php -S 0.0.0.0:88 -t .`!

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem was that the requested file was in my OneDrive folder. I moved the DocumentRoot out of OneDrive and it all worked!

Comment: I am having the same problem with OneDrive.  I can move it to another folder and it works just fine but I wanted to keep it in OneDrive so that I could easily sync the code between my laptop and my desktop.

Comment: Yeah, now OneDrive is better integrated with NTFS.

Comment: I figured out how to get OneDrive to work with PHP.  Go into the OneDrive settings and uncheck the "Files On-Demand" button.  Then after everything has downloaded, it worked.  What I think was happening was that PHP was requesting a file from OneDrive but only getting a zero-byte stub back.  https://i.imgur.com/lukjm4n.png

Answer (score 2):

In my case index.php worked for other sites. To the site that had problems index.html file worked but not index.php. It caused the error message like in the first message of this thread.

The culprit was scandinavian 'ä' in the directory path of the site on Windows's file system of my site. I changed it to 'a' and restarted the server. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with **UwAmp**. I solved it changing the name of a folder on my path, from `Formación` to `Formacion`, removing the accent mark, that seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was apparently caused by having the aliased folder in a different drive to the C:/ drive. I moved the folder to C:/ drive and it rectified the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you must set permissions for SYSTEM's group, not only for your current user. Properties -> security (or something like that), then select SYSTEM > Edit > Allow Full Control > OK

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions problem you would need to right click on the document Properties > Security Click on everybody or SYSTEM depending on if its XP or win 7/Vista edit thier permissions to allow them to read and execute.

For Reference [Click Here](http://www.computerforum.com/120722-using-wamp-editing-file-permissions-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is messed up in your code when requiring a file:

> C:/wamp/www/app/index.php

Is not a valid path on a windows machine, windows uses "\" for a directory separator while linux/unix/mac uses a "/".

In PHP never hard code directory slashes, use the constant:

> DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

To allow your code to run seamlessly on any platform.

Answer (score -1):

For the people who wants to know how i solved this.

The issue was with the file permission of `index.php` file, when i changed the file permission for `index.php` it worked.