# WAMP Error - Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/....' (include_path='.;c:\php\includes') in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, apache, server, wampserver

I've been searching around for hours now and can't seem to find any solutions.
I've been using WAMP Server on window for forever now, but suddenly last night I get the errors

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0.
>   Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/Users/User/www/OMG/index.php' (include_path='.;c:\php\includes') in Unknown on line 0

now to test this out, I've only created an index.php file with the following

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>
```

I still receive the errors. It doesn't matter if I use localhost/OMG or a virtual host address om.g

I've been pulling my hair out, and cant find anything that works from inside the php.ini, etc...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: There are a few questions on stackoverflow which may can help you: [18674298](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674298), [28893474](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893474) or [37427612](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427612).

Comment: Or [2917673](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037757/2917673)

Comment: Thanks guys but iv already seen these posts previously before asking myself. Nothing has worked.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using?

Comment: Where did you install WAMPServer?